# How to prove the Hahn-Banach constructively

Tags: banach-spaces, real-analysis, vector-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, operator-norms

I am just wondering, how to prove the Hahn-Banach theorem constructively for a *finite dimensional* normed vector space.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Comment: I am not sure this question reflects the level of this site. I am a bit puzzled about the attention it gets.

Comment: @Andras: IMHO, the question might be borderline, but it is definitely not trivial (or at least, it is as non-trivial as the usual proof of the Hahn-Banach theorem, where the inductive step is actually a bit delicate).

Comment: I believe that constructive versions of the Hahn-Banach theorem have been studied in several papers by Thierry Coquand.  You might look at, e.g., his paper "Geometric Hahn-Banach Theorem" in Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. (2006), 140, 313.

Comment: I was confused because this is usually optional homework on my beginning FA course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way as for the infinite dimensional case, except you avoid Zorn's lemma by counting dimensions.

Comment: Isn't the whole thing trivial as soon as you know that your subspace is complemented?

Comment: Preserving norms isn't trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to show that one can extend a linear functional from an $n$-dimensional space to a space of dimension $n+1$ without increasing its norm. See, for instance, [my notes](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nikita/31002/hahn-banach.pdf) (Lemma E.2)

In fact, by doing so, you can prove THBT constructively for any separable space.